# PHP does not execute, even though it reads variables

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, get, submit

i have a php file, where i want the user to select values from two dropdown lists, and after submit some code to be executed. After testing i have noticed, that it reads, the first echo, where it informs the user that has chosen these 2 specific values, but all the other code, that is supposed to display the connections of these two values, does not execute. I feel i am preety close, but i need some push i think. Below is the code

```
<form method="GET" action="">
    <table>
    <tr><br /><br /><center><h2>Επιλέξτε τις ομάδες για τις οποίες θέλετε να δείτε το ιστορικό</h2><center><br /></tr>
    <tr>
    <td><i>Επιλογή 1ης ομάδας</i></td>
    <td>
        <select id="Team1" name="Team1"><option value="0">Καμία επιλογή</option>
        <?php
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'leagueengine_data';
$table2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'leagueengine_tournament_matches';
$teams = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE data_type = 'team' ORDER BY data_value ASC");
foreach ( $teams as $teams ) 
{   $team_id = $teams->id;
$team_name = $teams->data_value;
echo '<option value="'.$team_id.'">'.leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($teams->id,'data_value') .'</option>';
}
$output .= '</div>';
?>  
</select>
</td></tr>
<tr>
    <td><i>Επιλογή 2ης ομάδας</i></td>
    <td>
        <select id="Team2" name="Team2"><option value="0">Καμία επιλογή</option>
        <?php
global $wpdb;
$table = $wpdb->prefix . 'leagueengine_data';
$table2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'leagueengine_tournament_matches';
$teams2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE data_type = 'team' ORDER BY data_value ASC");
foreach ( $teams2 as $teams2 ) 
{   $team2_id = $teams2->id;
$team2_name = $teams2->data_value;
echo '<option value="'.$team2_id.'">'.leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($teams2->id,'data_value') .'</option>';
}
$output .= '</div>';
 ?> 
 </select>
 </td></tr>
 </table>

<input type="submit" value="Αναζήτηση ιστορικού"><br />
</form>
<?php
$teamhome = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Team1']);
$teamaway = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['Team2']);
$table2 = $wpdb->    prefix . 'leagueengine_tournament_matches';

 echo '<div id="show">';

  if (isset($_GET["Team2"])) {
echo "<center>Επιλέξατε να δείτε την προϊστορία μεταξύ των ομάδων"; 

  echo '<b> '.leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($teamhome, 'data_value').'</b>';
  echo ' και <b>'.leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($teamaway, 'data_value').'</b></center>'; 
    $gbeet = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT count(*) FROM $table2 WHERE home_team_id = '$teamhome' AND away_team_id = '$teamaway' AND winner <> '' OR  home_team_id = '$teamaway' AND away_team_id = '$teamhome' AND winner <> ''");
    $home_team_wins = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table2 WHERE (home_team_id = '$teamhome' AND away_team_id = '$teamaway' or home_team_id = '$teamaway' AND away_team_id = '$teamhome') AND winner = '$teamhome'");
    $away_team_wins = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table2 WHERE (home_team_id = '$teamhome' AND away_team_id = '$teamaway' or home_team_id = '$teamaway' AND away_team_id = '$teamhome') AND winner = '$teamaway'");
    $homepnts1 = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT SUM(home_team_score) FROM $table2 WHERE home_team_id = '$teamhome' AND away_team_id = '$teamaway' AND winner <> ''");
    $homepnts2 = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT SUM(away_team_score) FROM $table2 WHERE home_team_id = '$teamaway' AND away_team_id = '$teamhome' AND winner <> ''");
    $homepnts= ($homepnts1) + ($homepnts2);
    $awaypnts1 = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT SUM(home_team_score) FROM $table2 WHERE home_team_id = '$teamaway' AND away_team_id = '$teamhome' AND winner <> ''");
    $awaypnts2 = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT SUM(away_team_score) FROM $table2 WHERE home_team_id = '$teamhome' AND away_team_id = '$teamaway' AND winner <> ''");
    $awaypnts= ($awaypnts1) + ($awaypnts2);



    $output .= '<br/><h2><center><b>Αναμετρήσεις ομάδων</b></center></h2>';
    $output .= '<span><center><i>Οι ομάδες έχουν βρεθεί αντιμέτωπες <b>'.$gbeet.'</b> φορές.</i></center></span>';
    $output .= '<table class="tournament_match_attributes">';

$output .= '<tbody><tr>';
$output .= '<th width="40%" style="text-align:center;"><b>'.leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($teamhome, 'data_value').'</b></th>';
$output .= '<th width="20%"></th>';
$output .= '<th width="40%" style="text-align:center;"><b>'.leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($teamaway, 'data_value').'</b></th>';
$output .= '</tr><tr>';
$output .= '<td>'.$home_team_wins.'</td>';
$output .= '<td><b>Νίκες</b></td>';
$output .= '<td>'.$away_team_wins.'</td>';
$output .= '</tr><tr>';
$output .= '<td>'.$homepnts.'</td>';
$output .= '<td><b>Πόντοι</b></td>';
$output .= '<td>'.$awaypnts.'</td>';
$output .= '</tr></tbody>';

                $output .= '</table>';

                $output .= '<table class="tournament_match_attributes">';
                $games = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table2 WHERE home_team_id = '$teamhome' AND away_team_id = '$teamaway' AND winner <> '' OR home_team_id = '$teamaway' AND away_team_id = '$teamhome' AND winner <> '' ORDER BY match_date DESC;");


$output .= '<tbody><tr>';
$output .= '<th style="text-align:center;"><b>Τουρνουά</b></th>';
$output .= '<th style="text-align:center;"><b>Ημερομηνία</b></th>';
$output .= '<th style="text-align:center;"><b>Αγώνας</b></th>';
$output .= '<th style="text-align:center;"><b>Σκορ</b></th></tr>';
foreach($games as $games) {
$date_of_match = $games->match_date;
$dom = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($date_of_match));
$Ateam = leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($games->home_team_id,'data_value') ;
$Bteam = leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($games->away_team_id,'data_value') ;
$Ascore = $games->home_team_score;
$Bscore = $games->away_team_score;
$tourne = leagueengine_fetch_data_from_id($games->tournament_id,'data_value') ;


$output .= '<tr><td>' .$tourne. '</td>';
$output .= '<td>'.$dom. '</td>';
$output .= '<td>'.$Ateam.' - '.$Bteam.'</td>';
$output .= '<td>'.$Ascore.' - '.$Bscore.'</td>';
$output .= '</tr>';
}
$output .= '<tr></tbody>';

                $output .= '</table>';
  }
                ?>
```

Comment: Change `foreach ( $teams2 as $teams2 ) ` to `foreach ( $teams2 as $team2 ) ` and use `$team2` inside the `foreach` and check.

Comment: I tested it. It stops producing even the 2 lists with this change.

Comment: no code is executed below this point
--> $gbeet = .....

Answer (score 0):

Realy sorry for the useless, as it seems post. Everything worked out, after i replaced output with echo :/